# Objective-C: need to call a method in another class from FinishedLaunching

Tags: objective-c

I got this far... here is my code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
    //  create the d/b or get the connection value
    SQLiteDB *dbInstance = [[SQLiteDB alloc] init];
}
```

Now, the question is:  this bit of code is supposed to check to see if a database exists, and if not, create it.  My problem is I am having a problem figuring out *exactly how* to write the first line of the called method and where to place it in SQLiteDB.m.  Is this an instance method (-) or a class method (+)?

I'm sorry for being so lame on this, but once I see it, I'll have the hang of it... the rest of the code is written in C#, and I can handle the conversion to Obj_C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a method to copy an existing database from your Bundle to the Documents directory, but can easily be adapted for a new database.  Just use the `fileExistsAtPath:` method logic below and replace the actions to take with your custom database creation code.

Put this in your AppDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)prepareDatabase
{
    //add Database Versioning check to see if the resources database is newer
    // generally as simple as naming your database with a version on the end

    NSFileManager *filemanager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURDATABASE.s3db"];
    if(![filemanager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]) {
        //Database doesn't exist yet, so we copy it from our resources
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingString:@"/YOURDATABASE.s3db"];
        if([filemanager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:nil]) {
            NSLog(@"Database Copied from resources");           
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Database copy FAILED from %@ to %@",defaultDBPath,databasePath);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method call this:

```
[self prepareDatabase];
```

Comment: theChrisKent:  that's EXACTLY the information I was looking for... thank you so much!  And thank you to the others that replied.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "see if the database exists" you mean "see if the database file exists on disk". For that, you use method `fileExistsAtPath:` of class `NSFileManager`. It's an instance method, but you can use `[NSFileManager defaultIntance]`.

Calculate the path to the file first (it's up to you how). Check if the file exists. If yes, open the file, if not, create a new database with that filename.

Comment: In iOS and Mac OS X v 10.5 and later you should consider using [[NSFileManager alloc] init] rather than the singleton method defaultManager. Instances of NSFileManager are considered thread-safe when created using [[NSFileManager alloc] init].

Comment: Even a thread-safe file manager won't save from a race condition in a "check/if not found, create" scenario.

Comment: Thanks.. I already had the logic, but still don't know what the method looks like... I want to call the method (don't know if it's instance or class method) from the code above.  I think I have the call correct, but don't know what the target code looks like (I just need the first line, i.e. - (id) initSQLiteDB...)